# JIRA/Greenhopper - Alter fields in the "Add Sub-task" form

Tags: jira, greenhopper

In Greenhopper, when I am in the Task Board, I have parent tasks and click the gear icon -> Add Sub-Task.  The form opens up to add sub-tasks, sub-features, whatever.  Does anyone know if there is a way to configure what fields show up on this form popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I hate to post a "me too" non-answer, this isn't as easy as it appears. The screen that's spawned isn't the workflow screen, nor the default screen, nor the screens that are configured for create/edit/view for the specified issue type in the relevant screen scheme. This is baffling.

Answer (score 1):

They changed how this works, you don't have to mess with JIRA's "screens" anymore.  Just go into Tools > Configuration > Card Styles in Greenhopper and add fields to the card view for your issue types.

Answer (score 0):

In Jira 4.4 you can do it in Administration mode on Issue types page.
Select 'Administration' > 'Issues' > 'Issue Types' > 'Sub-Tasks' (tab) to open the 'Sub-Tasks' page.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Sub-tasks